# The heat stream through multilayer walls is the same in each layer. Why sum up each heat stream to calculate temeperature difference?

Tags: thermodynamics

In stationary situation the heatstream that goes accross each layer of the wall is the same.

[image]

Accorsding to Fouriers law, we know that:

Φ = $\frac{k_1 S (T1 – T’)}{ d_1}$

Φ = $\frac{k_2 S (T’ – T’’)}{d_2}$

Φ = $\frac{k_3 S (T’’ – T2)}{d_3}$

However when we calculate the temperature difference between T1 and T2 we add all the heatstreams. Meaning logically speaking we should have something like 3Φ.

$T1–T2 = \frac{Φ}{S} (\frac{d_1}{k_1} + \frac{d_2}{k_2} + \frac{d_3}{k_3})$

But isn't this contradictory to the fact that $Φ_{in} = Φ_{out}$ as the stram is the same?

Could someone please explain what I may have misunderstood?

Answer (score 1):

You are not adding heat streams, otherwise you would get $3\Phi$. What have been added are temperature differences: $(T_1-T')+(T'-T'')+(T''-T_2)=T_1-T_2$.

Comment: yes but you write $T1–T2 = \frac{Φ}{S} (\frac{d_1}{k_1} + \frac{d_2}{k_2} + \frac{d_3}{k_3})$ which equals $T1–T2 =(\frac{Φd_1}{k_1} + \frac{Φd_2}{k_2} + \frac{Φd_3}{k_3})$ which is a sumation of fractions of heat streams. I see what you mean about the left side of the equation, but what about the right side?

Comment: Well, $T_1-T'=\Phi d_1/k_1$ and so on.

Answer (score 0):

The heat flow that enters layer 1 on the left leaves layer 1 on the right and enters layer 2.  The heat flow that enters layer 2 on the left from layer 1, leaves layer 2 on the right and enters layer 3.  The heat flow that enters layer 3 on the left from layer 2, leaves layer 3 on the right.  It's all the same heat flow.  There aren't 3 separate heat flows.

Comment: yes I know that. But the question is about the math. Why do we add the flows up?

Comment: Oh.  So it's the math.  OK.  You have 3 linear algebraic equations in the 3 unknowns $\Phi$, T', and T''.  Do you know how to solve 3 linear algebraic equations in three unknowns.  For this particular set of equations, there's a trick you can use that simplifies things.  Solve each equation for the temperature difference, and then add the 3 resulting equations together.  This eliminates T' and T'', and allows you to solve directly for $\Phi$